# Filtering Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap using seaborn from 200 variables, however I am interested in plotting only those variables that have more than 0.5 correlation with the dependent variable (The first column of the df).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have found the solution by modifying the df.corr() values before ploting the heatmap. Thx